# Is there some way to make Mailbox for Mac access my Mac "Contacts" for recipients?

Tags: macos, email, gmail

I'm using the Mailbox for Mac app. (It's the latest version, which is 0.4.0 at the time I'm posting this.)

When I type names into the recipients field, it shows me some names (I *assume* they're names in my gmail contacts, but I'm not sure).

But it doesn't show me names in my contacts. I think it used to, but I know other clients I've used have offered me *both* the contacts taht gmail's servers have for my account AND the contacts on my Mac. So...

**Is there some setting or trick to get Mailbox to access my Mac contacts?**

Comment: Total agreement about the on-topic ness of this. I've edited out the meta beta conversation (see the history if anyone is curious). Could you put the version of the app you're running into the text in case that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Mailbox website](http://www.mailboxapp.com/help/#/4423):

> On the desktop, contacts are currently populated from emails that are synced with Mailbox. We don't have a way to import your contacts from your email accounts at this time.
>
> We're planning multiple contact improvements down the road, including full contact integration in the future.

On a side note, you know about the ban on questions for software not publicly released, but you didn't search the relevant website for assistance before posting? Tsk, tsk. ;)

Comment: Thanks! Fair poke, but I *did* search their website. Maybe I should be *more* embarrassed that I failed to find it, (checking now, I may have been looking at info for the mobile app) but I did make the effort, and really do appreciate the help!